# Javascript variable state after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new in the web programming and I don't fully understand some simple things.
Suppose we have following ajax request:

```
var records = [];
   $.ajax(
   {
        url : "index", 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response)
        {
           records = response;
        }                
   });
   alert(records.length);//This displays 0
   alert(records.length);//This alert correctly displays number of records
```

The problem is that the array **records** appears empty, if I try to use them immediately after calling ajax (first alert displays zero length, while second alert displays correct length). What's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: There should be a general warning when asking this question, as it's asked at least 50 times every day!

Comment: Javascript is non-blocking!

Comment: Please do a little bit more research before you ask this kind of questions.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put your alert *inside* the success callback.

```
   var records = [];
   $.ajax(
   {
        url : "index", 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response)
        {
           records = response;
           alert(records.length);  // will always be correct
        }                
   });
```

In your example, the behavior will be unpredictable and will depend on how fast the call returns.

Answer (score 2):

The A in Ajax stands for *Asynchronous*

The success function doesn't trigger until the HTTP response comes back.

When the first `alert` fires, it hasn't come back. In the time it takes for you to click OK to that `alert`, the response has arrived so the success function has run by the time the second `alert` fires. (`alert` is a blocking function).

Do your work on the data in the success function, not immediately after sending the HTTP request.